# One to many records inside of accordion

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to group records by a specific field (parent) and display the child records inside of an accordion for that parent record. I first tried to use `GROUP BY` but that only returned one child record. Also, as the accordions work with id numbers, I have to increment that id for each accordion that is displayed.

I changed my SQL to `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY` but now it obviously doesn't group them.

```
SELECT `edition`, `rep`, `rep_name`, `serial` FROM `vouchers` as `v`
        INNER JOIN `reps` as `r` ON r.`rep_id` = v.`rep`
        WHERE `sp_id` = :sp_id ORDER BY `edition`
```

I managed to get the accordion ID bit working but can't figure out how to get it to show the `$value->edition (parent)` as the accordion title and the `$value->serial (child)` records inside the accordion.

```
<div class="m-accordion m-accordion--bordered" id="m_accordion_2" role="tablist">
  <?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data['voucher_history'] as $history=>$value):
      $i++;
  ?>
  <div class="m-accordion__item">
    <div class="m-accordion__item-head collapsed" role="tab" id="m_accordion_2_item_1_head" data-toggle="collapse" href="#m_accordion_2_item_<?php echo $i; ?>_body" aria-expanded="    false">
      <span class="m-accordion__item-icon">
        <i class="fa flaticon-user-ok"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="m-accordion__item-title">
        <?php echo sanitize($value->edition) . ' - ' . $value->rep_name; ?> 
      </span>
      <span class="m-accordion__item-mode"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="m-accordion__item-body collapse" id="m_accordion_2_item_<?php echo $i; ?>_body" class=" " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="m_accordion_2_item_2_head" data-parent="#m_accordion_2">
      <div class="m-accordion__item-content">
        <p>
          <?php echo sanitize($value->serial); ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```